# Trying to use PHP to write 102 almost identical Excel formulas...and getting confused by the loop-in-loop construction

Tags: php

For `100` companies, I have collected data for `102` days. I need to calculate some averages and am therefore trying to write a php script that writes the necessary `102` formulas for me, as follows:

```
=AVERAGE('panel-mv3'!BP2+'panel-mv3'!BP104+'panel-mv3'!BP206 ... +'panel-mv3'!BP8876)
=AVERAGE('panel-mv3'!BP3+'panel-mv3'!BP105+'panel-mv3'!BP207 ... +'panel-mv3'!BP8877)
=AVERAGE('panel-mv3'!BP4+'panel-mv3'!BP106+'panel-mv3'!BP208 ... +'panel-mv3'!BP8878)
...
=AVERAGE('panel-mv3'!BP103+'panel-mv3'!BP205+'panel-mv3'!BP307 ... +'panel-mv3'!BP8977)
```

As you can see, horizontally the formula needs to add `102` to each `BP` cell (`2, 104, 206, 308, 410, etc`). 
So the dots (`...`) mean the formula needs to be extended with `+'panel-mv3'!BP308+'panel-mv3'!BP410` etc up untill
`+'panel-mv3'!BP8876`. In each consecutive formula, the row values shift one: `BP3, 105, 207, etc...`

I've been trying to accomplish this using the code below, but I haven't finished it since I get confused

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 103; $i++) { // 102 dates
  echo "=AVERAGE(";
  for ($j = 1; $j < 101; $j++) { // 100 companies
    echo "'panel-mv3'!BP" . ($i + $j) . "+";
    echo "'panel-mv3'!BP" . ($i + $j) + ($j * 102) . "+";
    echo "'panel-mv3'!BP" . ($i + 1) + (($i * 2) * 102) . ")";
  }
}
```

Comment: So just to clarify you want the average of the 100 companies for each day? (102 formulas)

Comment: Are they all supposed to be `'panel-mv3'`? You have some `'panel-mv2'` in your first block of code?

Comment: typo corrected...yes, they are all supposed to be `panel-mv3` :-)

Comment: If you know PHP why are you using Excel and not a mysql database?

Comment: a side note: 8876 corresponds to 87th place and not to 100th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

for ($i = 2; $i < 104; $i++) { // 102 dates
  echo "=AVERAGE(";
  for ($j = 0; $j <= 99; $j++) { // 100 companies
    echo "'panel-mv3'!BP" . ($i + $j*102);
    if($j!=99) echo "+";
  }
  echo ")\n";
}
```

here is the runing fiddle http://codepad.org/Z4lEQ74d but it dies with timeout (as it is a free account)

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks! (And I also now learned about codepad! I knew SQLFiddle but not PHPFiddle :-)

Comment: your welcome, this one is more clear http://writecodeonline.com/php/ but can't post the example url there